# Python-Bioformats Image plane too large issue

Tags: python

I'm trying to use `python-bioformats` to open a `.jp2` image.

It throws the `loci.formats.FormatException`, as it is greater than the 2GB limit. The message suggests using the `openBytes` method found in the `loci.formats.IFormatReader` of the Java library.

Where ( and if ) can I find the `openBytes` method within the python module?

Comment: Since you posted no code, I assume the documentation might suffice: http://pythonhosted.org/python-bioformats/_modules/bioformats/formatreader.html Theres the method `openBytes`

Comment: I'd recommend asking on the OME forum at https://www.openmicroscopy.org/community/, or the mailing lists: https://www.openmicroscopy.org/support/ - these are the Bio-Formats community support resources.

Comment: Thank you both, I found the method though the image I'm trying to open (a .jp2) is still too big, so onto next challenge.